# How to get leave page confirmation in Opera? Any other way?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, opera

The leave page confirmation is working fine with all browsers except Opera.

I need to do the leave page confirmation which supports Opera. Please can anyone give some suggestions to do that, or edit my code? This may help me a lot.

My JavaScript code is:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return  "Are you Sure want to LOGOUT the session ?";
};
```

Comment: Did a search and StackOverflow has lots of posts about how Opera doesn't yet support onbeforeunload. Other suggest using onunload instead for Opera but it's not a great solution obviously.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Searched a lot.But it shows onbeforeunload is not supported in opera.I need some trick to do the same function.is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

onbeforeunload is now supported since Opera 15 !